# White Screen when trying to connect to a MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, apache2

I've got just a simple script below to try to confirm whether I can connect to my database:

```
<?php

$mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
if ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
   echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;
}
else {
   echo "Connected.";
}

?>
```

I am running Ubuntu on VirtualBox and I can use mysql on the command line with no problem. I've also tested that apache2 and PHP both work by loading up a sample php file.

I'm sure there is probably some configuration that I'm missing but when I looked at /etc/php5/conf.d I didn't see anything that might mess me up.

Please help!

Comment: white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: And I have changed the values in the $mysqli_connection string to match those on my system.

Comment: I added those two comments and I still just get a blank screen.

Comment: view source? blank or the php or ?

Comment: When I click 'view source' that is also blank.

Comment: Also when running 'php mytest.php' from the command line I get PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function - so I'm sure I'm missing something, just not sure what.

Comment: Of course View Source would be blank if nothing is being echoed to the page.

Comment: If it's saying undefined function, that's exactly what's happening - you are calling a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: Found out what the issue was. I didn't have the PHP MySQL modules downloaded.